# Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4.I started with Fxml files and I am cant attach them to controllers

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, plugins, openjdk-11

```
JDK:11.0.8
Netbeans: 12.1
```

I have been looking for hours on the internet. Kinda new on java so it jyst doesnt feel good. Kindly help me with this error. I tried changing JDK but that didnt work too. I dont know if the maven FXML archaetype supports Java Fx
Thanks in advance

**Login.fxml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
    
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="503.0" prefWidth="687.0" style="-fx-background-image: C:Users;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mycompany.lmsfront.LoginController" >
       <children>
          <ImageView fitHeight="509.0" fitWidth="715.0" layoutX="-12.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
             <image>
                <Image url="file:/C:/Users/Ahmad%20Bilal/Documents/NetBeansProjects/LMSFront/src/main/java/com/mycompany/lmsfront/jaime-lopes-0RDBOAdnbWM-unsplash.jpg" />
             </image>
          </ImageView>
          <Pane layoutX="141.0" layoutY="97.0">
             <children>
                <Accordion />
             </children>
          </Pane>
          <Pane layoutX="400.0" layoutY="228.0">
             <children>
                <Accordion />
             </children>
          </Pane>
          <AnchorPane layoutX="170.0" layoutY="88.0" opacity="0.7" prefHeight="334.0" prefWidth="391.0" style="-fx-background-color: #606060FF;">
             <children>
                <TextField layoutX="56.0" layoutY="97.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="282.0" promptText="Username" style="-fx-background-color: White;" />
                <Text fill="WHITE" fontSmoothingType="LCD" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="64.0" opacity="0.77" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Sign In" wrappingWidth="125.0">
                   <font>
                      <Font size="34.0" />
                   </font></Text>
                <Button fx:id="#Loginbutton" defaultButton="true" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="235.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#InvalidlabelOnAction" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="97.0" style="-fx-background-color: Black;" text="SignIn">
                </Button>
                <PasswordField layoutX="56.0" layoutY="167.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="282.0" promptText="Password" />
             </children>
          </AnchorPane>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

**LoginController.java**:

```java
package com.mycompany.lmsfront;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class LoginController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private ImageView bgimg;
    
            
    @Override   
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        File ImgFile = new File("file:/C:/Users/Ahmad%20Bilal/Documents/NetBeansProjects/LMSFront/src/main/java/com/mycompany/lmsfront/jaime-lopes-0RDBOAdnbWM-unsplash.jpg");
        Image Imgptr= new Image(ImgFile.toURI().toString());
        bgimg.setImage(Imgptr);
    }   
    
    
    @FXML
    private Button Loginbutton;
    @FXML
    private Label Invalidlabel;
           
    public void InvalidlabelOnAction(ActionEvent event){
     Invalidlabel.setText("Invalid Login");       
    } 

 }
```

**Main.java**:

```java
package com.mycompany.lmsfront;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
    

 public class App extends Application {
    
     @Override
     public void start(Stage stage)  throws IOException {
        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Scene scene=new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
     }
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           
        launch(args);
     }
 }
```

And here's the error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Ahmad%20Bilal/Documents/NetBeansProjects/LMSFront/target/classes/com/mycompany/lmsfront/Login.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at com.mycompany.lmsfront/com.mycompany.lmsfront.App.start(App.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.lmsfront/com.mycompany.lmsfront.LoginController.initialize(LoginController.java:25)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application com.mycompany.lmsfront.App
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:504)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:504)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  5.081 s
Finished at: 2020-12-06T01:16:00-08:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project LMSFront: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Your error is `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='InvalidlabelOnAction'`. Make sure that method (with the correct signature) is in your controller class. And when linking methods to FXML elements you need to use a `#` prefix. For example, `onAction="#methodName"`.

Comment: Kindly take a look at the stack trace @Slaw. I updated it. Thankfully the error you told were taken down but there are still quite a few.

Comment: Before moving forward, I suggest reading [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [ask]. Your question formatting is a mess and that hinders the ability of people to help you. Please [edit] your question to make it readable. Note that stack traces should be formatted as code; they're much easier to read that way.

Comment: Two problems: (1) You didn't give your `ImageView` an `fx:id` which means it can't be injected–I suggest reading a tutorial on JavaFX and FXML as you seem to be making basic mistakes—and (2) you should read [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am working on it and yes giving an ID worked very well.